# Access localhost:3000 through localhost/myproject/index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, localhost

I am new to node.js and I would like to learn if I could access the node.js port (3000) by writing the url of the index.html. I followed [this tutorial](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) to create a chat app, but I have the problem I mentioned above.

I want to be able to write **localhost/myproject/index.html** instead of **localhost:3000** on my browser.

My server-side javascript code is this:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Is there something I should change here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be interesting why you want to use the app routing in that way?

Comment: which web server you are using

Comment: I use WAMP which has the apache server

Comment: With Apache you can setup a reverse proxy that redirects requests to localhost/myproject/* to localhost:3000

Answer (score 3):

If you want run your project as domain name instead of localhost:3000 then just follow this link
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: Could you explain in not many words what you suggest to do? Also, what do I do since I use Windows and not Ubuntu? Note that I use WAMP, so I should change the already existed files, I think.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to access your path without defining a port you would need to use port 80 or port 443 for https.

```
http.listen(80, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:80');
});
```

Concerning the path you should adjust the routing parameter, also have a look at [static files](http://expressjs.com/de/starter/static-files.html) in express js.

```
app.get('/myproject/index', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am now able to access the index by writing **localhost:3000/myproject/index.html**. But how can I use the port 80 as you said?

Comment: you are welcome, have a look at the updated question

Comment: Thanks for your update, but this didn't work. It shows the page, but the things done by node.js do not work. I assume I must change the port that node.js uses from the settings, or something like that

Comment: On which system you are running on? On linux you should do `sudo node ...` - you need special permission for port lower than 1024.

Comment: I use windows ! Do you know what I should do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145264/discussion-between-thanasis-and-ju).